# What algorithm is used in Haskell (GHC) for deriving types of recursive expressions?

Tags: haskell, recursion, ghc, type-inference, hindley-milner

Consider the following examples:

#### Non-recursive functions

```
 f x = x
 g y = f 'A'
```

GHC infers `f :: a -> a`

#### Mutually recursive functions

```
 f x = const x g
 g y = f 'A'
```

Now GHC infers `f :: Char -> Char`, even though the type could be `a -> a` just in the previous case.

#### Polymorphic recursion

```
 data FullTree a = Leaf | Bin a (FullTree (a, a))

 size :: FullTree a -> Int
 size Leaf = 0
 size (Bin _ t) = 1 + 2 * size t
```

Here GHC isn't able to infer the type of `size`, unless its explicit type is given.

---

So it seems that Haskell (GHC) doesn't use polymorphic recursion (as described in [Alan Mycroft: Polymorphic type schemes and recursive definitions](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~am21/papers/icop84.pdf)), because it can't infer polymorphic types in examples 2 and 3. But in the first case it correctly infers the most general type of `f`. What is the exact procedure? Does GHC analyse the dependencies of expressions, groups them together (like `f` and `g` in the second example) and uses monomorphic recursion type inference on these groups?

Comment: Type inference for polymorphic recursion is undecidable in general, that's why it's not done.

Comment: @augustss That's true, but perhaps there are some variants (as suggested in Section 7 of Mycroft's paper) that allow some polymorphism, while still being total. Or one could just pragmatically run the non-terminating procedure for polymorphic recursion and set some arbitrary limit for the number of cycles.

Comment: @PetrPudlák: the Mercury language does an iterative inference like that for polymorphic recursion, FYI.

Comment: Yes, you can do inference for much polymorphic recursion.  But putting a type signature is a very small burden, and very easy to explain.  So we opted for that.

Comment: "We"?! Wow. I've just realised that @augustss is _the_ Lennart Augustsson of Haskel Report fame. How many of the committee are on SO?

Comment: Btw, it was possible to do polymorphic recursion in Haskell even before it was allowed with a type signature.  But it was a bit tricky. :)

Comment: @augustss That's interesting, when it wasn't allowed, and what was the trick?

Comment: @PetrPudlák If your function has typing `f :: A -> B` you make a class, `class C a where f :: a -> B` and an instance `instance C A where f = ...`.  Then you can use `f` polymorphically inside `...`.  Of course, you still had to give a type signature, but it was for a method rather than a function.  I discovered this before polymorphic recursion was allowed for functions, and since you could do it with this trick nobody objected to doing it directly for functions instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does GHC analyse the dependencies of expressions, groups them together (like f and g in the second example) and uses monomorphic recursion type inference on these groups?

Yes, exactly this happens. The Haskell 2010 report has a [section](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-880004.5) on the topic.